# Knockout - Viewmodel transformation

Tags: knockout.js

From the client side i have to make multiple ajax calls to a REST service that would give me three different domain models in JSON. Now at the client side i have to transform them into a viewmodel before binding them to the controls. Which would mean transforming them into a completely different structure with presentation only data. Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/RJGQw/

```
var vm1 = {
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'some name',
    Address1: 'Some street somewhere',
    City: 'New York',
    Country: 'USA',
    Zip : '11111'
};

var vm2 = {
    title: 'Mr',
    designations: ['Chief', 'Boss', 'Lord'],
    secrets: ['xxxxx','yyyyy','zzzzz']
};


var vmCombines = function(data1, data2){
    return {
        combinedName: ko.observable(data2.title +  ' ' + data1.Name),
        designation: ko.observable(function(){
            if(data2.designations.length == 0)
                return '';

            return data2.designations.join();
        }()),
        Address: ko.observable(function(){
            return data1.Address1 + ', ' + data1.City + ',' + data1.Country + ',' +     data1.Zip
        }())
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new vmCombines(vm1, vm2));
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: combinedName"/><br />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: designation"/><br />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Address"/><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

var viewModel = JSON.parse(jsonContentFromService);

Maybe something like this then:

```
var mainVM = {};

mainVM.SomeStuffFromVm1 = vm1.WhateverYouNeed
mainVM.SomeStuffFromVM2  = vm2.WhateveryYouNeed;
```

Comment: My scenario is to call var customerViewModel = JSON.parse(jsonContentFromService1);  var employeeViewModel = JSON.parse(jsonContentFromService2); and then construct another viewModel called screen1ViewModel which will have a few select data from the employeeViewModel and customerViewModel. Thats the scenario i am trying to achieve

Comment: You can construct a new object based on the other three

Answer (score 0):

You should check out John Papa's course on Single Page Web Applications. He describes an architecture that I'm sure would suit your needs. Though he only has one web API, there is no difference in architecture if using multiple.

In brief, you want a model module that defines the shape of your client side objects (`model.employee` and `model.customer`). Then your view model module contains view models that contain (among other things) one or more of these objects. E.g. `vm.employees` would contain a list (`ko.observableArray`) of employee objects, and `vm.employeesAndCustomers` would contain a `ko.observableArray` of employees with their associated customers. If you want a view model that only has partial data from a `model.employee` object and partial data from a `model.customer` object, then you need to define a new model such as `model.employeeBrief` and `model.customerBrief`, then define a view model that uses a list of such items.

You should use a `dataservice` module to retrieve data from services, and a `datacontext` module to convert the received JSON into lists of client side (model.*) objects, and hold an in memory list of these. View models receive their `observableArrays` from the `datacontext`.

The `datacontext` will use a `model.mapper` module to convert the received JSON into their client side form.